# Why "grep -q -v" only works with single line input?

Tags: command-line, grep, terminal

If I use `grep -q` in combination with `-v` to return 0 if there are no matches or 1 if there is a match, it works as long as input is a single line:

```
$ echo 'abc' | grep -q -v a; echo $?
1
$ echo 'abc' | grep -q -v x; echo $?
0
```

But if the input is multi-line, grep will always return 0:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc' | grep -q -v a; echo $?
0
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc' | grep -q -v x; echo $?
0
```

What is the reason for such behavior?

I know that the correct way in this case would be to use `! grep -q` instead of `grep -q -v`, but I still want to know the answer.

Comment: Line 2 made grep succeed in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per grep manual:

```
-v, --invert-match
         Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.
```

If you supply only one line `abc` and tell `grep` to select only lines not matching `a` you get an empty output and return code equal to 1.

If you supply three lines `a`, `b`, and `c` and tell `grep` to select only those not matching `a` you get `b` and `c` in output and 0 as a return code.

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc' | grep -v a; echo $?
b
c
0
```